# ADO.NET Max Pool Size Behavior

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I'm using MSSQL 2008R2. I wrote a C# app and *purposely did not* **close** my SqlConnection. Debugging locally on VS 2010. Following is the code I used:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "server=s; database=db; User ID=sa; Password=p; Max Pool Size=1;Connect Timeout=3";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Numbers";
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        //reader.Read() and display results to Textbox1.Text
    }
```

Max Pool Size = 1; was expecting to error out on second click try on 2nd browser.
Why is it I can go to 3 different browsers (Mozilla, Chrome, IE) and call click method once each. That equates to 3 simultaneous connections right? The timeout error only occurs when I use a browser, but call method twice on that browser. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there appears to be a discrepancy between debugging locally in VS 2010 and IIS 7.5. I had to deploy the sample web site to IIS for the max pool size to behave as expected. If I try to call click event a second time no matter which browser I try, it will throw timeout error, this is expected. Perform website/app pool restart/recycle as needed to retest.

For some reason debugging locally in VS 2010 bypasses max pool size restriction. Each browser may call click event which in my example opens 3 sqlconnection objects. The only time it throws the timeout error is if you stay in a browser and call click method twice. Strange behavior but something developers should be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you left the connection object open doesn't imply three separate connections. The .NET framework actually leverages the connection pooling in SQL Server and manages it by connection string. Since the connection string was the same for all three requests - and the connection was available - there is no conflict.

Now, if you were to simulate a situation where you had a long running query start up on one of the requests and then try and hit it again - you would probably find that it would wait first - and you would get a timeout exception.

Here is a [lengthy and dry document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx) on connection pooling in the .NET framework on MSDN.

Comment: In the link you posted, they enclose sqlconnection object with using{} block which closes connection and returns it to the pool once it exits scope, my example does not. Connection pooling will reuse connections but if I choose not to close connection, it must create another pool. My query is very quick, only 10 digits returned.

Comment: @invulnarable27: Yes, they are issuing the `using` statement and that's a good practice, so keep that in mind. But, not relevant to your situation. However, **since the first query is short**, when it builds a new connection, it's **not going to create additional connections in the pool.** **Remember, the pool works on the connection string.** As stated in the second paragraph, if you were to create a *long running query on the first request* and then on the subsequent request try and create another connection it would fail as expected because it would need to *get another one from the pool.*

Comment: I agree with you that a long running query will hold onto the sqlconnection causing a second connection to be created on subsequent request. I simulate a long query(indefinite) by not calling connection.Close(). Errors out just as expected when deployed in IIS, VS does not behave correctly.